# Using length of string in each row of column of df as argument in a function

Tags: python, pandas

I am having some serious trouble with this! Suppose I have a pandas dataframe like the following:

```
Name    LeftString    RightString
nameA   AATCGCTGCG    TGCTGCTGCTT
nameB   GTCGTGBAGB    BTGHTAGCGTB
nameC   ABCTHJKLAA    BFTCHHFCTSH
....
```

I have a function that takes the following as arguments:

```
def localAlign(minAlignment, names, string1, string2):
    # do something great
```

In my function, minAlignment is an integer, names, string1, and string2 are dataframe columns being used as list objects by the function.

I then call the function at a later point:

```
left1_2_compare = localAlign(12, df['Name'], df['LeftString'], df['RightString'])
```

My function runs with no issues, but the 12 is passed in as a hard coded value, or as a sys argument, but what I would rather it be is a variable that is 60% the length of the df['LeftString'].

So what I have tried in regards to this is to pass in a calculation that would return an int to the function argument:

```
left1_2_compare = localAlign((int(len(df['LeftString'])*0.6)), 
                             df['Name'], df['LeftString'],
                             df['RightString'])
```

The interesting part about this is that the code doesn't fail or return errors, it just doesn't output anything for that value (the output file is blank for this part). The rest has data produced and good.

We see that the df has been defined before the function is called, is there a way to use the length of string in row1...rown as the input integer for the function without defining it inside of the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need Series created by [`len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html), multiple by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html) and cast to inttegers by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
left1_2_compare = localAlign((df['LeftString'].str.len().mul(.6)).astype(int), 
                             df['Name'], 
                             df['LeftString'], 
                             df['RightString'])
```

Comment: This looks nice, I am looking into it now.

Comment: It is interesting, saying it cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer.

Comment: @d_kennetz - it means there are missing values, so need `df['LeftString'].str.len().mul(.6)).fillna(0).astype(int)`

Comment: Ahhh thanks there are NA values, sorry the df is large and I forgot about these because I was hardcoding this until now.

Comment: This has fixed it, thanks for your help! Very cool answer. Maybe consider adding the fillna to the answer as edge case, and I don't think it has a negative effect.